# 2D Game dev and Java. Other possibilities than OpenGL?

Tags: 2d, java

I recently started to program some basic OpenGL stuff in Java, but OpenGL and DirectX is too much to handle and to understand for me and I'm getting bored really fast.

Now I am wondering if there are other possibilities than OpenGL (or DirectX) to make simple 2D graphics and to get started in Game Development, even if its limited. I will probably use OpenGL anyway when I am more experienced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is also the library [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) which provides the most common features for developing 2D games (images, animations, sounds, gameloop...). It has the advantage over the Java 2D library to be more specific to video games as it includes collisions checking and a physics engine.

Comment: Slick wraps OpenGl and hides the "hard stuff"

Comment: Slick is a great library and I highly recommend it. Unlike many game engines which force you to do things their way Slick gets out of your way and let's you focus on getting things done.

Comment: I will definitely try this, it seems really good

Comment: I highly recommend Slick

Comment: Slick has been deprecated for years as of 2018.

Answer (score 9):

Of course! Java has a built in [Java 2D library](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) which requires no OpenGL or DirectX knowledge, and I highly recommend starting with it! In fact, it has pretty okay performance.

The essential starting point is to define your own class which extends Frame (or Applet), and then override the `paint(Graphics g)` method and use `g` to draw to the screen.

Comment: Indeed, nothing wrong with Java 2D. Just cast g to Graphics2D though, or you'll throw away all the things that make it good.

Comment: I like this answer (+1) because it suggests a pure-Java solution that doesn't require any third-party libraries that have non-Java components (e.g., such as those written and compiled in ASM/C/C++).

Comment: Yep, which makes it 100% portable (cross-platform), stable (since the Java 2D library has presumably been better tested than many of the 3rd party libraries out there), well-supported, and easy to develop and deploy. I also recommend the book "Developing Games in Java" by David Brackeen; in it, he develops a software 3D engine using only Java 2D, and the book of course explains it step-by-step including the math involved and the decisions and optimizations made along the way. It's very impressive and broken down so it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply use Swing or Awt for a start (for 2D)? If you correclty design your game (I mean, a well though MVC design), you will be able to upgrage your game with a better game display engine later. The main goal, if you're working alone, is to quickly achieve to have something displayed on the screen, is'nt it ? It boosts your enthusiasm ...

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly intended for games, but [Processing](http://processing.org/) is quite popular for 2D canvas graphics, it might be interesting to check.

Answer (score 2):

Try basic canvas libraries if you are looking to develop just 2D games. I actually learn't to use 2D canvas by building a game on it right about the time this question was posted :) Now I am graduating to webGL.