# What are some good resources on creating and reading 2D game levels in Java?

Tags: 2d, java, level-design

Could some resources be listed in relation to the creation and management of simplistic, efficient 2D game levels, that are available for use with Java?

Comment: Have a look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/2d-game-dev-and-java-other-possibilities-than-opengl too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) or [OGMO Editor](http://ogmoeditor.com/). These editors allow you to create your levels and can also write the level-data to XML. Parsing the XML data in Java should be rather simple. Alternatively you could have a look at the [AndEngine](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/) which comes with a [parser for the TMX format](http://www.andengine.org/blog/2010/07/andengine-tiledmaps-in-the-tmx-format/) (TMX is an XML format written by Tiled).

Answer (score -3):

try to look at [www.processing.org](http://www.processing.org) it's a simple and quite power system for making 2d in java

Comment: Processing is its own langauge, meant for image manipulation; how does this relate to the question at all?

Comment: with "use processing.org" i mean add the jars of this frameworks (it is not a properly a language..) and use its easy library for xml and 2d graphic. probabilly i did not understand the question